# Embedded CSS only affects some input fields

Tags: php, css

I have a form on a landing page with two type inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="enter your email" id="email">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="GO">
```

After PHP validates my form, if successful, I have this code in my PHP script:

```
if($result){ // If successful
                        echo '<style>input[type="submit"],input[type="text"]{display:none;}</style>';
                        echo '<p class="success">Thank you for registering!</p>';
                    }
```

The issue is that only the submit input is hidden - while the text input remains.  I've tried isolating just the "text" input using the exact same code structure; the class on the p tag also functions.  Does anybody know the reason for this?

Comment: You can place `.success` element on that inputs you dont want user to see with `position:relative;` <3

Comment: That CSS selector _does_ select both submit and text input fields, and works correctly. Ergo: The code you have shown us is not the relevant one, resp. not enough to reproduce the problem. Might f.e. be that you have another CSS rule somewhere with higher specificity, that leads to the text input still being visible.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could do it in an easier way:

```
if ($result) { // If successful
    echo '<p class="success">Thank you for registering!</p>';
}
else {
    echo '<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="enter your email" id="email">
          <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="GO">';
}
```

But the best way is - Javascript

Comment: Saying "the best way is Javascript" and then not explaining why is not helpful in this situation.

Comment: Both commands need to execute if successful.  The else clause runs an error message not included in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it should work.

```
if($result){ // If successful
                        echo '<style>input[type=submit],input[type=text]{display:none;}</style>';
                        echo '<p class="success">Thank you for registering!</p>';
                    }
```

Comment: No luck. Didn't work.  I believe "submit" and "text" need to be in quotes to be semantically correct.

Comment: The change you made is subtle, so it would be helpful to explain what it was. For reference, he removed the quotation marks around submit and test in the selectors.  Also, in this case, I don't believe that this is a correct solution, as [https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-attribute-values](the use of quotes shouldn't matter in attribute selectors). [http://jsfiddle.net/apkostka/5mvyc3n7/](proof).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the id's as selectors, seems like it would be more dependable.

```
if ($result) {
    echo '<style>#submit,#text{display:none;}</style>';
    echo '<p class="success">Thank you for registering!</p>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution:

Create a hidden div outside of the form section.

```
<p class="hidden">Thank you for registering.</p>
```

On submit, hide the form and display the div:

```
echo '<style>section#form{display:none;}</style>';
echo '<style>p.hidden{display:inherit;}</style>';
```